# need a way to send input to XPATH of a searchbox using requests replacing my current seleniumDriver

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

```
 your_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='<This opens up the search box>']")
 your_input.click()
 time.sleep(2)
 search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='<search box class>']")
 search.clear()
 search.send_keys(f'{city}, {state}')
 search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
 time.sleep(5)
```

I need to input a list of 1000 to this search box and the selenium driver is taking too long to complete wanted to see if there is anything that I can do with python requests:

the search box input only changes a part of the page and the url doesn't change I have no clue on how to achieve it to make it faster